# Android Studio 1.0.2 m2respository gradle issue

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, android-studio

Using Android Studio 1.0.2, and you are forced to use Gradle 2.2.1, all system variables are correct. With the new update there are issues with older versions of gradle and m2repository. I am trying to import kickflip.io android example (https://github.com/Kickflip/kickflip-android-example).

I am seeing this error:

```
Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android     Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.1/gradle-2.2.1.pom
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android     Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.1/gradle-2.2.1.jar
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.1/gradle-2.2.1.pom
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.1/gradle-2.2.1.jar
Required by:
    :kickflip-android-example-master:unspecified
```

I've looked in m2repository and see:

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository\com\android\tools\build\gradle\1.0.0
```

How can I add the 2.2.1 library?

Gradle Wrapper:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

Top-level build file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'
        classpath 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-backports-compat23:2.3.5'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

app/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'
    compile 'io.kickflip:sdk:1.1.1'
}
```

My error report is extremely long, so won't post it since the formatting gets corrupted when I copy and paste it in. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The version of Gradle is 2.2.1, but you're plugging that into the place where the version number of the Android Gradle plugin goes. That's currently at 1.0.0.  Instead of this:

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'
```

use this:

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
```

Comment: I am now getting the following error:Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/2.2.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error: Could not find or load main class 2.2.1

Comment: That's a different question, and one that's been asked a lot before.

Answer (score 1):

yes, it works.

Firstly the jcenter repository not includes 2.2.1 version. so need to change to 1.0.0/1.0.1