# Cache It is currently in use by another Gradle instance

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I don't understand why this is happening.

```
Gradle sync failed: Timeout waiting to lock buildscript class cache for build file '/Users/user/Documents/android-studio-pubble/App/build.gradle' (/Users/user/.gradle/caches/2.2.1/scripts/build_bqh4uod6cat7u5cm5qkoye2ky/ProjectScript/buildscript). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
         Owner PID: unknown
         Our PID: 909
         Owner Operation: unknown
         Our operation: Initialize cache
         Lock file: /Users/user/.gradle/caches/2.2.1/scripts/build_bqh4uod6cat7u5cm5qkoye2ky/ProjectScript/buildscript/cache.properties.lock
         Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

general gladle is:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url '/Users/user/Documents/sdk/extras/android/m2repository' }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation" << "-Xlint:unchecked"
    }
}
```

App gradle file is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        pubblemod {
            keyAlias 'testapp'
            keyPassword 'testapp'
            storeFile file('/Users/user/Documents/sdk/testapp.keystore')
            storePassword 'testapp'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {

        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.intellij:annotations:+@jar'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:22.0.+'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.2.+'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.0.0'
    compile 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.7.7.0'
    compile 'it.neokree:MaterialTabs:0.11'
    compile 'com.github.johnkil.android-appmsg:appmsg:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.cocosw:bottomsheet:1.+@aar'
    compile 'de.psdev.licensesdialog:licensesdialog:1.7.0'
    compile 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.7.7.0'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.7'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1+'
    compile project(':loadingLibrary')
    compile project(':welcomeLibrary')

//    compile project(':licenceDialogLibrary')
    compile project(':Bootstrap')
}
```

It used to work and then i wanted to add a new module and it all went downwards after that. Does anyone had this problem and solved it? I don't even know what is wrong..or how i made this.

Comment: I know you've probably tried it, but have you cleaned your project and/or restarted your compiler?

Comment: i tried, and no luck, i cannot compile my project anymore and no clue what is wrong

Comment: Duplicate question, this solved the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27806990/android-studio-1-0-2-m2respository-gradle-issue

Comment: Just restarting the Studio, issue got resolved for me.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this is to be delete a cache.

For Windows it's under `C:\Users\Administrator\.gradle\caches`

For Mac OSX it's `~/.gradle/caches`

Try to execute the following command:

```
find ~/.gradle -type f -name "*.lock" | while read f; do rm $f; done
```

Comment: Invalidating cache through the option in Android Studio File > and restarting didn't work for me, but this did! +1