# Gradle 6.7.1: gradle wrapper command arises "Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry"

Tags: gradle, gradlew

Having

- Windows 10
- Linux Ubuntu 18.04
- Mac El Capitan

All of them with Gradle installed with the unique version **6.7.1**

All these OS have the following:

- custom `GRADLE_HOME` location (therefore the `.gradle` default location is **not** used)
- custom `GRADLE_USER_HOME` location (therefore the `.gradle` default location is **not** used)
- A `wrapper-incubator` simple directory (**empty**) that is used to execute just the two commands mentioned later just below.

For Windows and Linux:

When the following commands are executed:

- `gradle wrapper` (generates the expected files)
- `gralew --version` (downloads the gradle wrapper to `GRADLE_USER_HOME/wrapper/dists`)

All work fine.

The problem is with Mac. It always happens the following with the `gradle wrapper` command (`--debug` used):

```
...
2020-12-09T15:03:18.049-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2020-12-09T15:03:18.049-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2020-12-09T15:03:18.049-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2020-12-09T15:03:18.050-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2020-12-09T15:03:18.050-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2020-12-09T15:03:18.050-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2020-12-09T15:03:19.325-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] The file lock is held by a different Gradle process. I was unable to read on which port the owner listens for lock access requests.
2020-12-09T15:03:19.581-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] The file lock is held by a different Gradle process. I was unable to read on which port the owner listens for lock access requests.
2020-12-09T15:03:21.431-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] The file lock is held by a different Gradle process. I was unable to read on which port the owner listens for lock access requests.
2020-12-09T15:03:22.210-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] The file lock is held by a different Gradle process. I was unable to read on which port the owner listens for lock access requests.
2020-12-09T15:03:22.686-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] The file lock is held by a different Gradle process. I was unable to read on which port the owner listens for lock access requests.
2020-12-09T15:03:24.388-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] The file lock is held by a different Gradle process. I was unable to read on which port the owner listens for lock access requests.
2020-12-09T15:03:26.167-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] The file lock is held by a different Gradle process. I was unable to read on which port the owner listens for lock access requests.
2020-12-09T15:03:27.169-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] The file lock is held by a different Gradle process. I was unable to read on which port the owner listens for lock access requests.
2020-12-09T15:03:28.047-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2020-12-09T15:03:28.047-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2020-12-09T15:03:28.047-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2020-12-09T15:03:28.048-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2020-12-09T15:03:28.048-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2020-12-09T15:03:28.049-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2020-12-09T15:03:29.095-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] The file lock is held by a different Gradle process. I was unable to read on which port the owner listens for lock access requests.
2020-12-09T15:03:30.096-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] The file lock is held by a different Gradle process. I was unable to read on which port the owner listens for lock access requests.
2020-12-09T15:03:30.099-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService] Worker lease root.1 completed (0 worker(s) in use)
2020-12-09T15:03:30.099-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Daemon worker: released lock on root.1
2020-12-09T15:03:30.101-0500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
2020-12-09T15:03:30.103-0500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
2020-12-09T15:03:30.106-0500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
2020-12-09T15:03:30.106-0500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 1: Task failed with an exception.
2020-12-09T15:03:30.107-0500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] -----------
2020-12-09T15:03:30.107-0500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
2020-12-09T15:03:30.107-0500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Gradle could not start your build.
2020-12-09T15:03:30.107-0500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Could not create service of type ComponentMetadataRuleExecutor using DependencyManagementBuildScopeServices.createComponentMetadataRuleExecutor().
2020-12-09T15:03:30.107-0500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    > Timeout waiting to lock cache directory md-rule (/Volumes/FP27072011/gradle/repository/caches/6.7.1/md-rule). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
2020-12-09T15:03:30.107-0500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]      Owner PID: unknown
2020-12-09T15:03:30.107-0500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]      Our PID: 959
2020-12-09T15:03:30.108-0500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]      Owner Operation: unknown
2020-12-09T15:03:30.108-0500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]      Our operation:
2020-12-09T15:03:30.108-0500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]      Lock file: /Volumes/FP27072011/gradle/repository/caches/6.7.1/md-rule/md-rule.lock
2020-12-09T15:03:30.108-0500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
2020-12-09T15:03:30.108-0500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
2020-12-09T15:03:30.108-0500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.  Run with --scan to get full insights.
2020-12-09T15:03:30.108-0500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] ==============================================================================
2020-12-09T15:03:30.109-0500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
2020-12-09T15:03:30.109-0500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 2: Task failed with an exception.
2020-12-09T15:03:30.109-0500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] -----------
2020-12-09T15:03:30.109-0500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
2020-12-09T15:03:30.109-0500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Timeout waiting to lock artifact cache (/Volumes/FP27072011/gradle/repository/caches/modules-2). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
2020-12-09T15:03:30.109-0500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Owner PID: unknown
2020-12-09T15:03:30.109-0500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Our PID: 959
2020-12-09T15:03:30.109-0500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Owner Operation: unknown
2020-12-09T15:03:30.109-0500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Our operation:
2020-12-09T15:03:30.110-0500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Lock file: /Volumes/FP27072011/gradle/repository/caches/modules-2/modules-2.lock
2020-12-09T15:03:30.110-0500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
2020-12-09T15:03:30.110-0500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
2020-12-09T15:03:30.110-0500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.  Run with --scan to get full insights.
2020-12-09T15:03:30.110-0500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] ==============================================================================
2020-12-09T15:03:30.110-0500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
2020-12-09T15:03:30.110-0500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
2020-12-09T15:03:30.110-0500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger]
2020-12-09T15:03:30.111-0500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 2m 4s
2020-12-09T15:03:30.114-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Build finished for file system watching' started
2020-12-09T15:03:30.115-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Completing Build operation 'Build finished for file system watching'
2020-12-09T15:03:30.115-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Build finished for file system watching' completed
2020-12-09T15:03:30.115-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Completing Build operation 'Run build'
2020-12-09T15:03:30.115-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Run build' completed
2020-12-09T15:03:30.188-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for cache directory md-supplier (/Volumes/FP27072011/gradle/repository/caches/6.7.1/md-supplier)
2020-12-09T15:03:30.188-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on cache directory md-supplier (/Volumes/FP27072011/gradle/repository/caches/6.7.1/md-supplier).
2020-12-09T15:03:30.206-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess] Cache Configuration Cache (/Users/manueljordan/whiteroom/gradle/wrapper-incubator/.gradle/configuration-cache) was closed 0 times.
2020-12-09T15:03:30.217-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.deployment.internal.DefaultDeploymentRegistry] Stopping 0 deployment handles
2020-12-09T15:03:30.217-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.deployment.internal.DefaultDeploymentRegistry] Stopped deployment handles
2020-12-09T15:03:30.218-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for file hash cache (/Users/manueljordan/whiteroom/gradle/wrapper-incubator/.gradle/6.7.1/fileHashes)
2020-12-09T15:03:30.218-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on file hash cache (/Users/manueljordan/whiteroom/gradle/wrapper-incubator/.gradle/6.7.1/fileHashes).
2020-12-09T15:03:30.219-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for checksums cache (/Users/manueljordan/whiteroom/gradle/wrapper-incubator/.gradle/checksums)
2020-12-09T15:03:30.219-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on checksums cache (/Users/manueljordan/whiteroom/gradle/wrapper-incubator/.gradle/checksums).
2020-12-09T15:03:30.220-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess] Cache VCS Checkout Cache (/Users/manueljordan/whiteroom/gradle/wrapper-incubator/.gradle/vcs-1) was closed 0 times.
2020-12-09T15:03:30.220-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess] Cache VCS metadata (/Users/manueljordan/whiteroom/gradle/wrapper-incubator/.gradle/6.7.1/vcsMetadata-1) was closed 0 times.
2020-12-09T15:03:30.242-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.VersionSpecificCacheCleanupAction] Processed version-specific caches at /Users/manueljordan/whiteroom/gradle/wrapper-incubator/.gradle for cleanup in 0.02 secs
2020-12-09T15:03:30.252-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild] The daemon has finished executing the build.
2020-12-09T15:03:30.343-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientInputForwarder] Dispatching close input message: org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.CloseInput@5b4e669a
2020-12-09T15:03:30.343-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 20: dispatching class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.CloseInput
2020-12-09T15:03:30.344-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient] Received result Success[value=org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildActionResult@75d0911a] from daemon DaemonInfo{pid=959, address=[7fd2a6a1-ecb0-4f97-b150-d5e6a1705f55 port:49491, addresses:[/127.0.0.1]], state=Busy, lastBusy=1607544088030, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=c48c63f2-8b5a-4580-8a89-d85e12aefdd1,javaHome=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.0.9.1+1/Contents/Home,daemonRegistryDir=/Volumes/FP27072011/gradle/repository/daemon,pid=959,idleTimeout=10800000,priority=NORMAL,daemonOpts=--add-opens,java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED,-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xms256m,-Xmx512m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=PE,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]} (build should be done).
2020-12-09T15:03:30.344-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: dispatching class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.Finished
2020-12-09T15:03:30.344-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: connection stop
2020-12-09T15:03:30.349-0500 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.launcher.cli.DebugLoggerWarningAction]
#############################################################################
   WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING

   Debug level logging will leak security sensitive information!

   https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/logging.html#sec:debug_security
#############################################################################
```

I have the same situation even:

- Mac is re started
- `GRADLE_USER_HOME` location is deleted and created
- `gradle --stop` is executed

When I execute the `gradle --status` command I get:

```
gradle --status
   PID STATUS   INFO
   959 IDLE     6.7.1 
   874 STOPPED  (stop command received)
```

BTW - For each and after of `gradle wrapper` execution a new daemon is created and remains in IDLE, for the next execution I must execute `gradle --stop` just to be sure no daemon is running around and theoretically avoid deadlocks

I read the following links:

- [It is currently in use by another Gradle instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523508/it-is-currently-in-use-by-another-gradle-instance)
- [Cache It is currently in use by another Gradle instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059212/cache-it-is-currently-in-use-by-another-gradle-instance)

For the `ps -A | grep gradle` command shows:

```
ps -A | grep gradle
  959 ??         0:14.90 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.0.9.1+1/Contents/Home/bin/java --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xms256m -Xmx512m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=PE -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp /Users/manueljordan/whiteroom/gradle/6.7.1/lib/gradle-launcher-6.7.1.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 6.7.1
  997 ttys000    0:00.00 grep gradle
```

From above not sure why Java appears.

BTW

- The same command on Linux shows nothing.
- The 3 OS have the same Java version

How to resolve this situation?